# Issue in executing a command in perl

Tags: perl

I have the below code:

```
chdir glob "/home/test/test1/test2/perl*";
@testList = exec "cat test.in | grep build | awk '{print \$2}'";
foreach my $testList(@testList) {
    chdir "/home/test/test1/$testList";
    exec "cat test.out | grep -w 'PASSED'";
}
```

After I run the above code, it gives the output for only the below:

```
chdir glob "/home/test/test1/test2/perl*";
@testList = exec "cat test.in | grep build | awk '{print \$2}'";
```

but not the other two lines below. I only want the output for the lines:

```
foreach my $testList(@testList) {
    chdir "$opts->{/home/test/test1$testList";
    exec "cat test.out | grep -w 'PASSED'";
```

and not

```
chdir glob "/home/test/test1/test2/perl*";
@testList = exec "cat test.in | grep build | awk '{print \$2}'";
```

Please help.

Comment: Can you provide sample input files so we can reproduce the problem?

Comment: That pipeline is a long way to go for `awk '{ if(/build/) {print $2} }' < test.in`.

Answer (score 0):

`exec` and `system` are returning exit code.

Try:

```
@testList = `cat test.in | grep build | awk '{print \$2}'`;
```

Comment: thanks for the quick reply but if I remove exec and mention only the above line then the result is not coming in @testList

Comment: Actually, `exec` never returns.